# $lookup aggregation for nested array object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have `category` collection which has subcategory embedded object. I need to write aggregation script to first lookup from this collection to `storelisting` collection. Then add the storelisting fields to the corresponding subcategories.

#### category

```
{
  "_id": "",
  "categoryName": "",
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "subCategoryId": "",
      "subCategoryName": "",
      "storeListingIds": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ]
    },
    {
      "subCategoryId": "",
      "subCategoryName": "",
      "storeListingIds": [
        "3","4","5"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "order": 2,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-01T22:26:11.669Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-04-27T17:17:25.442Z"
  },
  "_class": ""
}
```

#### storelisting

```
{
  "_id": "1",
  "storeListingName": "",
  "storeListingUrl": "",
  "catalogueIds": [
    ""
  ],
  "_class": ""
},
{
  "_id": "2",
  "storeListingName": "",
  "storeListingUrl": "",
  "catalogueIds": [
    ""
  ],
  "_class": ""
},
{
  "_id": "3",
  "storeListingName": "",
  "storeListingUrl": "",
  "catalogueIds": [
    ""
  ],
  "_class": ""
},
{
  "_id": "4",
  "storeListingName": "",
  "storeListingUrl": "",
  "catalogueIds": [
    ""
  ],
  "_class": ""
},
{
  "_id": "5",
  "storeListingName": "",
  "storeListingUrl": "",
  "catalogueIds": [
    ""
  ],
  "_class": ""
}
```

I need to lookup form above collection to storeListing collection. I want all the fields of storeListing also.

Result should be look like this:

```
{
  "_id": "",
  "categoryName": "",
  "subCategories": [
    {
      "subCategoryId": "",
      "subCategoryName": "",
      "storeListingIds": [
        "1",
        "2"
      ],
      "storeListings":[
        {
          "_id": "1",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        },
        {
          "_id": "2",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "subCategoryId": "",
      "subCategoryName": "",
      "storeListingIds": [
        "3","4","5"
      ],
      "storeListings":[
        {
          "_id": "3",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        },
        {
          "_id": "4",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        },
        {
          "_id": "5",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "order": 2,
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-01T22:26:11.669Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2021-04-27T17:17:25.442Z"
  },
  "_class": ""
}
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough.. Which collection u need to join? How do `storeListingName` and others come?

Comment: @varman We have two collection category and storelisting, We need to join category and storelisting. To join this we need to check the ids from "subCategories.storeListingIds". storeListingName attribute comes from storeListing collection. This is the document of storelisting collection:
{
          "_id": "4",
          "storeListingName": "",
          "storeListingUrl": "",
          "catalogueIds": [
            ""
          ],
          "_class": ""
        }

Answer (score 1):

#### Explanation

1. We perform `$lookup` for nested `storeListingId` and store the result in the `tmp` field
2. We apply filtering and merge `subCategories` object with `storeListings` values

**Note:** The reason why we use `$mergeObjects` is to avoid naming every field in `subCategories`

```
$map: {
    input: "$subCategories",
    as: "subCat",
    in: {
        subCategoryId:"$$subCat.subCategoryId",
        subCategoryName:"$$subCat.subCategoryName",
        storeListingIds: "$$subCat.storeListingIds",
        storeListening: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$tmp",
                cond: {
                  $in: [ "$$this._id", "$$subCat.storeListingIds" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Try this one:

```
db.category.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "storelisting",
      localField: "subCategories.storeListingIds",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "tmp"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      tmp: "$$REMOVE",
      subCategories: {
        $map: {
          input: "$subCategories",
          as: "subCat",
          in: {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$subCat",
              {
                storeListings: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$tmp",
                    cond: {
                      $in: [ "$$this._id", "$$subCat.storeListingIds" ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PFY6tsK8sgD)